# Restarting delayed_job with cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, delayed-job

I would like to check each hour if delayed_job is running. For this I am using cron

29 * * * * /var/jenkins/jobs/Production/workspace/integration/check_runnig_jobs.sh

The script is given below.
When execute on its own, it starts delayed_job. But when executed from cron it fails to start and sends a mail to /var/mail/www-data which is:

19:19:01: begin checking...
19:19:01: checking delayed_job
- 19:19:01: not running, restarting...
Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
+ 19:19:01: delayed_job is RUNNING

After which delayed_job is not found in the running processes.

Could you assist us?

The script is

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check jobs that should be running on the production environment. This script might be    croned or run by jenkins,

check_process() {
  echo "$ts: checking $1"
  [ "$1" = "" ] && return 0
  [ `pgrep -fn $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
}

check_delayed_job() {
        RAILS_ENV=production
        export RAILS_ENV
        name="delayed_job"
        check_process $name
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "- $ts: not running, restarting..." &&    /var/jenkins/jobs/Production/workspace/script/delayed_job start
        [ $? -eq 1 ] && echo "+ $ts: $name is RUNNING"

        return 0
}

# timestamp
ts=`date +%T`

echo "$ts: begin checking..."
check_delayed_job

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you checked the [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem?

Comment: Delayed_job is actually working well, but I have problem starting it from cron, and I am looking for a way to get that fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - you have to add

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/jenkins/jobs/Production/workspace/script
export PATH
```

in the beginning of the script to set up the environment...